# How can I use multiple table in hibernate criteria dynamic query?

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have 2 entities

```
public class EstMast implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long estCode;
    private String estName;
    private String estName;
    private Long esttypeCode;
    private String activeYn;
}

public class DisabEst implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long runId;

    private Long estCode;

    private Long regionCode;

    private String spec;
}
```

I need to perform conditional query  if input 2 is not null I need to execute this query

```
SELECT est FROM EstMast est, DisabEst dis WHERE est.estCode = dis.estCode AND est.esttypeCode =:input1
```

and if input 2 is present I need to append one AND query(AND spec IN (:input2)), query looks like below

```
SELECT est FROM EstMast est, DisabEst dis WHERE est.estCode = dis.estCode AND est.esttypeCode =:input1 AND spec IN (:input2)
```

How can I achieve this using hibernate criteria dynamic query?

**What I tried so far** :

I had started using criteria.

```
Criteria accountCriteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(EstMast.class,"est");
```

Here how can I add the second table ?